# Как получить GET запрос, и отправить его в Telegram

Tags: php, get

как получить Get запрос уникального ID из адрессной строки и отправить вместе с формой в телеграм?

**Выглядит примерно так:**
domain.com?id=324 > получаем Get запрос id=324 > добавляем его в форму и отправляем в телеграм.

**Вот мой код:**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$telegram = $_POST['user_telegram'];
$description = $_POST['user_description'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$token = "5249994103:AAHZ8y_aQ3HcnbBrhxoLrtkDxspsqH610Pg";
$chat_id = "-753826972";
$arr = array(
  'id: ' => $id,
  'Name: ' => $name,
  'Telegram: ' => $telegram,
  'Description' => $description
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: /success');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

**Но по итогу, мне приходит форма в телеграм с пустым ID.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: запрос должен отправляться на domain.com?id=324 тогда в переменной $_GET['id'] будут твои данные, что в переменной $_GET можно узнать через print_r($_GET)

Comment: Данные в форму вводятся с адреса domain.com?id=324. Но сама форма отправляется методом POST, может в этом дело? И на самой страннице запрос GET обьявлял через echo $_GET['id'] - он есть. Но при отправке формы приходит пустое поле

Comment: Форму можно отправлять на url который содержит в себе get параметры, если ты говоришь что через echo ты получаешь id тогда смотри что в переменной $txt

Comment: В атрибуте `action` формы что написано?

Comment: <form action="telegram.php" method="POST" class="smart-contract__form">

Comment: И откуда тогда скрипт telegram.php возьмет id? Очевидно что __ниоткуда__. Следовательно надо написать как-то так `<form action="telegram.php?id=ТВОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ" method="POST"`

Comment: Либо можно на форму добавить скрытое поле в которое внести значение `$_GET[id]` и тогда telegram.php будет тянуть все нужные значения из `$_POST`.